# I am trying to use a tool tip but not sure how to make the trigger work

Tags: reactjs, drop-down-menu, tooltip, reactstrap

I want my tooltip to display on hover I am using `reactrap` `tooltip` and have been looking over the documentation for it but I cant seem to get the tooltip to call to my function that sets the state for it to be shown. This is my code:

```
 const PracticesList = () => {
    const [isShown, setIsShown] = useState(false);

const toggleToolTip = () => {
      console.log("MADE IT");
      setIsShown(!isShown);
    };

return allPractices.map((p) => (
      <DropdownItem
        key={p.id}
        toggle={false}
        tag="div"
        className={styles.submenuItem}
        onClick={() => {
          // only switch the practice if the practice selection has changed
          if (currentUser.currentPracticeID != p.id) {
            onSwitchPractice(p.id);
          }
          setMainDropdownOpen(false);
        }}
      >
        <span
          style={{ width: "300px", backgroundColor: "black", color: "blue" }}
          href="#"
          id="Tooltip"
        >
          {p.name}
        </span>
        <Tooltip
          placement="right"
          trigger="hover"
          isOpen={true}
          target="Tooltip"
          toggle={toggleToolTip()}
        >
          {p.name}
        </Tooltip>
      </DropdownItem>
    ));
  };
```

Note: this dropdown item is nested within another im not sure if this affects how tooltip is applied but any advice would be helpful. This is my first time using a tool tip this is the documentation ive been looking over for it [https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/[enter](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/%5Benter) link description here][1](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/tooltips/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you want to trigger a tooltip on hover of your `DropdowItem` element. The idea is likely to have multiple `DropdownItem`s, each of which will be associated with a tooltip.

You need to isolate each `DropdownItem` element with its tooltip into its own component, which will be very helpful as the their corresponding tooltips need the ability to mange their own states. Here is the idea:

```
const DropdownItemWithToolTip = (props) => {
  const [tooltipOpen, setTooltipOpen] = useState(false);

  const toggle = () => setTooltipOpen(!tooltipOpen);

  return (
    <div>
      <DropdownItem key={props.id} toggle={false} tag="div">
        <span href="#" id={"tooltip-" + props.id}>
          {props.name}
        </span>
      </DropdownItem>
      <Tooltip
        placement="right"
        trigger="hover"
        isOpen={tooltipOpen}
        target={"tooltip-" + props.id}
        toggle={toggle}
      >
        {props.name}
      </Tooltip>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Then your `PracticesList` element can be something as simple as:

```
const PracticesList = () => {
  return allPractices.map((p) => <DropdownItemWithToolTip key={p.id} {...p} />);
};
```

All it does is return a bunch of `DropdownItemWithToolTip`s. Rendering it is a piece of cake:

```
return (
    <div>
      <h3>Tooltip</h3>
      <PracticesList />
    </div>
  );
```

Here is a Sandbox for you: https://codesandbox.io/s/floral-architecture-01dv1?file=/src/App.js